# How to get the value of td using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to get the value or text which is inside td tag i have tried with custom attribute but failed . I am working for past two hours but I am getting undefined error.

here is the php code

```
$id=$row["id"];
$name=$row["name"];
echo "<tr class='inner'>";
echo "<td class='tdtext'check='$id' contenteditable='true'>".$row["name"]."</td>";
echo "<td><Button class='btn btn-primary buttonclass' tayyab='$id'>edit</Button>
    echo "</tr>";
```

this is the j Query code

```
$(".buttonclass").click(function(){
        var edit=$(this).attr("tayyab");
          var abc = $(this).siblings(".tdtext").html();
        alert(abc);
});
```

Comment: What have your tried?

Comment: i have tried with custom atrributes which is inside the td tag check which i have made but this also not works :(

Comment: Among siblings of a button there's no `td`

Comment: this->parent->previous or this->closest->previous or this->closest(.inner)->find(.tdcheck)->text

Answer (score 3):

You want to find the closest parent TD, then the previous TD

```
$(".buttonclass").click(function(){
    var edit = $(this).attr("tayyab");
    var abc = $(this).closest('td').prev(".tdtext").html();
    alert(abc);
});
```

Note that `tayyab` is an invalid attribute, and it should be `data-tayyab`